# MySQL find_in_set function not work as expect

Tags: mysql

Now I am using this command to query user_id not in collections, this is my sql:

```
select *
from report_user_foundation
where !FIND_IN_SET(user_id ,(
    select GROUP_CONCAT(login_user_ids) as bet_user_ids
    from report_summary rs 
    where statistic_time >= 1606752000000)
)
```

I query user id from table `report_user_foundation` that not in `report_summary` table `login_user_ids` column. but when the using the result user id to query in `report_summary` that still exists.

```
select login_user_ids 
from report_summary rs 
where login_user_ids like '%4685%'
```

Am I sql is not correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: Provide simplified sample - CREATE TABLE for both tables (only columns used in a query), INSERT INTO (3-5 rows per table), and desired output.

Comment: I finally find the reason, because the group_concat default length is 1024,the string was concat. @Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIND_IN_SET ( GROUP_CONCAT )` -- cleaver, but clunky.  Instead of

```
select *
from report_user_foundation
where !FIND_IN_SET(user_id ,(
    select GROUP_CONCAT(login_user_ids) as bet_user_ids
    from report_summary rs 
    where statistic_time >= 1606752000000)
)
```

do

```
SELECT *
    FROM report_user_foundation AS rsf
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM report_summary
                   ON rsf.user_id = login_user_ids
                  AND statistic_time >= 1606752000000
                    )
   /* AND login_user_ids like '%4685%' */
```

or, alternatively,

```
SELECT rsf.*
    FROM report_user_foundation AS rsf
    LEFT JOIN report_summary rs
                   ON rsf.user_id = rs.login_user_ids
                  AND rs.statistic_time >= 1606752000000
    WHERE rs.id IS NULL
   /* AND login_user_ids like '%4685%' */
```

Alas, I don't understand your comment about `where login_user_ids like '%4685%'`.  Perhaps it goes where I put the comments.

If these tables get big, this composite index may help:

```
report_summary:  INDEX(login_user_ids, statistic_time)
```